# Trying to get the 'source' url to salesforce leads (web-to-lead / salesforce)

Tags: api, web2lead, source

I am trying to get the page url (from where the user fills in the contactform) to my leads in salesforce. I've got this code so far:

```php
add_filter( 'salesforce_w2l_field_value', 'salesforce_w2l_field_value_querystring_example', 10, 3 );

function salesforce_w2l_field_value_querystring_example( $val, $field, $form ){

    $form_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 ); // form id to act upon
    $field_name = 'source__c'; // API Name of the field you want to autofill
    $qs_var = 'source'; // e.g. ?source=foo

    if( in_array( $form, $form_ids) && $field_name == $field ){
        if( isset( $_GET[ $qs_var ] ) ){
            return $_GET[ $qs_var ];
        }
    }

    return $val;

}
```

I've got it working a few months ago (for a couple of months) but unfortunately I deleted the old functions.php file when I updated the wordpress theme. So everything on the salesforce side should be fine, only this code.

Please let me know if you see the solution.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting an incorrect API name for the lead source field on the `Lead` object. Change `$field_name = 'source__c';` to the :

```
$field_name = 'LeadSource';
```

you can reference the following documentation to check all API names for fields on `Lead` object [SOAP API Developer Guide Lead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Oleksandr, but I am already using 'LeadSource' to generate the (company)name of that website to salesforce leads. Because I have multiple web-to-lead forms on 6 different websites. This single website has 29 web-to-lead forms.  So 'LeadSource' generates the name that website. But I also want the URL of where that lead filled in the contact form. for example: '/cleaning-service-price-list/'. I use to do that with this source__c code but it's not working. Any other idea's?  Maybe an other parameter? Beacause 'HTTP_REFERER' is working great for Referer url

Comment: Got it!! 'Request_uri' was the one that i was looking for. Now it's generating the page url again. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that's working for me now:

---

```
add_filter( 'salesforce_w2l_field_value', 'salesforce_w2l_field_value_querystring_example', 10, 3 );

function salesforce_w2l_field_value_querystring_example( $val, $field, $form ){

    $form_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 ); // form id to act upon
    $field_name = 'source__c'; // API Name of the field you want to autofill

    if( in_array( $form, $form_ids) && $field_name == $field ){
        if( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ){
            return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }
    }

    return $val;

}
```